# Excel Count Styles and Text Contents

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to Excel's VBA, and I've searched all over the web for this particular issue. Perhaps it's because I'm new to coding that the answer doesn't stand out to me, but here it is.

Originally, I wanted to use a formula that counts the styles within a range. After this, I wanted to return the number of cells that contain a certain text within that same range of styles.

For example, a list would be styled either good, bad, or normal. In addition, it would have either Bob, Joe, or Jane. In another place, I would attempt to count the number of times the word "Bob" comes up with the style "Good", and return it as a value. If "Bob" shows up a total of 10 times, but only 4 of them are styled good, then the count would return with "4". In addition, if the style "Good" turns up 5 times, but only 4 of them have the text "Bob" in it, the count would return with "4".

I have two formulas for this, but they only return either the count of the specific text, or the count of the specific style. Also, I want to specify the text to be counted only in the Formula, not in the VBA module.

VAR = CountStyleAndText("Bob",B2:B26)
*Counts "Bob" through cells B2 and B26 with the style "Good"*

This is the first code I came across, which counts the style within a range of cells

```
Function CountStyleGood(CellRange)
  Dim Item As Range, Total As Long
    For Each Item In CellRange
    ' Check to see if the cell is formatted as Style = "Good"
       If Item.Style = "Good" Then
          Total = Total + 1
       End If
     Next Item
        CountStyleGood = Total
     End Function
```

This is the second code I came across, which counts the text within a range of cells (Tested, but failed to make it work)

=count("find me",Range("A1:A100"))

```
function count(find as string, lookin as range) As Long
   dim cell As Range
   for each cell in lookin
      if (cell.Value = find) then 
         count = count + 1 '//case sens
    next
 end function
```

I figured something like this would do:

```
Function CountStyleAndText(CellRange, find As String, lookin As Range) As Long
   Dim Item As Range, Total As Long, Cell As Range 
   For Each Item In CellRange
      ' Check to see if the cell is formatted as Style = "Good"
      If Item.Style = "Good" And (cell.Value = find) Then
          Total = Total + 1
      End If
    Next Item
    CountStyleAndText = Total
 End Function
```

Remember, this is what you type into the cell to count:

=CountStyleAndText("Bob",B1:B26)

Comment: your code seems ok, what is the question...?

Comment: What does the VBA debugger says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to specify the style name in the "formula" (i.e. in the UDF call) then use:

```
Function CountStyleGood(find As String, lookin As Range, styleName As String)
    Dim Item As Range, Total As Long

    For Each Item In lookin
        If Item.Style = styleName Then If Item.Value = find Then Total = Total + 1
    Next Item
    CountStyleGood = Total
End Function
```

while if you want to hard code the style name:

```
Function CountStyleGood(find As String, lookin As Range)
    Dim Item As Range, Total As Long

    For Each Item In lookin
        If Item.Style = "Good" Then If Item.Value = find Then Total = Total + 1
    Next Item
    CountStyleGood = Total
End Function
```

either case remember that style name is case sensitive (i.e. "Good" is different from "good")